# Python - how to sort a tuple of tuple and list

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, tuples

I am new to python and struggling to sort. I have a following tuple and list in python.

`t = ((('s1',123),[10,1,23]), (('s2', 123),[4,1,12]), (('s3', 123),[22,1,30]),)`

I would like to sort the tuple by the 3 element from the list. Sort by t[0][2][2] = 23,12,30. 
So, it will return below:

`t = ( (('s2', 123),[4,1,12]), (('s1',123),[10,1,23]),  (('s3', 123),[22,1,30]),)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sorted()` as follows.

```
t = ((('s1',123),[10,1,23]), (('s2', 123),[4,1,12]), (('s3', 123),[22,1,30]))
t = sorted(t, key = lambda t: t[1][-1])
```

Comment: I resolved it like sorted(t, key = lambda x:x[1][2]) and it worked. I am assuming -1 represent last element from the list. Sorry I am new.

Comment: For the first element in t, t[1] denotes [10, 1, 23], and the index of final value of list or tuple is -1. Thus, t[1][-1] is 23, and it is your sorting criteria.

Comment: Yes it is. For example, if a list A = [1, 2, 3, 4], A[0] == 1, A[1] == 2, A[2] == 3, A[3] == 4, and A[-1] == 4, A[-2] == 3, A[-3] == 2, A[-4] == 1.